# Can I calculate the travel time between two points via the estimated average travel speed?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm contemplating the complexity (or simplicity?) of calculating an estimated time of arrival for an entity, without taking possible delays into account. If I know that the entity will travel at x speeds over y distances, what's the formula for ETA?

My thinking is that 25mph for 50 miles and 75mph for 50 miles is like 50 mph for 100miles.

I'm trying to workout whether it's more complex than I'm thinking

Comment: Does the speed ever change, or is it the same all along? (If it's the same, then the calculation is really simple. If the speed changes, then depending on how it changes it can be really difficult to calculate.

Comment: @Arthur it differs. 55mph for 25 miles, 75 for 50miles, etc

Comment: At a steady $50$ it takes $2$ hours. At $25$ then $75$, it already takes $2$ hours for the first $50$ miles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the whole run into chunks of equal lengths (like you've done with $50+50$) and you go with one speed in each chunk, then the total average speed isn't the usual average, but what is called the *harmonic* average. The harmonic average for $n$ numbers $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$ is $$\frac{n}{\frac1{x_1}+\cdots+\frac1{x_n}}$$ For your two numbers $25$ and $75$, the average speed is $$\frac2{\frac1{25}+\frac1{75}}=37.5$$ So $25$mph for $50$ miles then $75$ mph for $50$ miles takes the same amount of time as $37.5$mph for $100$ miles.

Another example: if you go $50$mph for $25$ miles and $40$mph for $50$ miles, then the chunks are of size $25$ miles (two of them you have the speed $40$mph), and the average speed is
$$
\frac3{\frac1{50}+\frac1{40}+\frac1{40}}=\frac{300}{7}\approx 42.856
$$miles per hour

Comment: So rather I need to calculate each strip of travel with a unique speed separately and add the results together. Correct?